# What is the word size ("bitness") for POSIX systems and/or Windows' SCS_POSIX_BINARY

Tags: windows, winapi, posix

While studying the WinAPI documentation, I stumbled across [SCS_POSIX_BINARY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getbinarytypew). Allegedly, MS Windows can somewhat execute POSIX executables (despite [Wine docs listing them as "not implemented"](https://source.winehq.org/WineAPI/GetBinaryTypeW.html))

Assuming POSIX executables can run, what is the standard word size ("bitness") for SCS_POSIX_BINARY ? For example, for MS Windows =< 2010, the word size is typically 32 bits. What would be the equivalent for POSIX, and/or for Microsoft's POSIX implementation if any?

Cheers

Comment: The Wine "not implemented" note is for Wine, not real Windows.

Comment: @Anders , while Wine definitely misses on "POSIX_BINARY", is there any info on whether the same applies to Windows? I mean, I don't think I ever encountered a Posix app within Windows

Comment: @tabdiukov, NT supports multiple subsystems, one of which used to be a POSIX subsystem. Initially it was very limited in 1993, but over the years it was fleshed out as Interix and eventually Subsystem for Unix Applications (SUA). Server 2012 / Windows 8 was the last version to support SUA. The NT subsystem design was never popular because an application still has to be ported. Only the Windows subsystem remains in Windows 10. Instead we now have the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), which is not an NT subsystem, but instead uses pico processes that execute Linux ELF binaries.

Answer (score 1):

The word size is always going to be <= the word size of the kernel so on a 32-bit OS it is going to be 32-bit for all the POSIX tools.

The Microsoft [website for SUA](https://web.archive.org/web/20050510064042/http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/R2/unixcomponents/webinstall.mspx) (2003 R2) says:

> These components include all utilities that install with Windows Services for UNIX 3.5. These are nearly 300 BSD-based and optional SUA GNU utilities. Many of these utilities (around 80) are also available in 64-bit version.

The only conclusion I can draw from this is that a 64-bit version of Windows supports both. To know for sure that this is accurate you would actually have to install SUA on a 64-bit machine.

`GetBinaryType` is a very old function so my guess is that it only checks <strike>if it's a POSIX PE and does not look at the machine type</strike>. If you actually care then you can just read the header yourself and see.

Edit:

I downloaded the SUA installer and took a look and it does include both 32 and 64 bit POSIX PE executables.

For 32-bit (dumpbin):

```
FILE HEADER VALUES
             14C machine (x86)
               C number of sections
        ...

OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES
             10B magic # (PE32)
         ...
           2736E checksum
               7 subsystem (Posix CUI)
```

`SCS_POSIX_BINARY` is returned as expected but for

```
FILE HEADER VALUES
            8664 machine (x64)
            ...

OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES
             20B magic # (PE32+)
           ...
               0 checksum
               7 subsystem (Posix CUI)
```

it actually returns `SCS_64BIT_BINARY`! So you do actually have to inspect the PE header yourself if you want the true answer.